# Could not find the format for this date: "2018-09-09T09:04:47+00:00"

Tags: date

*Getting Error*

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-09-09T09:04:47+00:00"
```

Whatis the date format is this?

Comment: ISO time with UTC timezone?? But to be real ISO it should end with Z

Comment: If he has read the problem that is the issue, I could not find what is the format then only I can write the formatter.

Comment: Yes @Antoniossss but this value I am getting through a service, I need to parse it to convert into timestamp.

Comment: @drowny ok. Thanks.

Comment: Thats not my problem that service uses custom time formats.

Comment: @Antoniossss ok I thought you are trying to help me, so was explaining the problem. But nevermind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'X' for timezone:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2018-09-09T09:04:47+00:00");
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rahim, this is exactly what I was looking for. Working perfectly.

Comment: It is better to use the new `java.time.*` classes than `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion, about this date format, so I will explain.

1. This is an ISO 8601 date-time value with a timezone offset.

   References:

   - The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) page in Wikipedia is accurate and pretty comprehensive.
   - The W3 Consortium have documented in a TR; [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).
   - The Official version may be obtained from ISO; [here](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html).
2. The `Z` is an ISO standard timezone specifier.  It means the same thing as `+00.00`, and is known in some circles (e.g. the military) as "Zulu time".
3. An ISO 8601 date/time does not "have to" end with a `Z`.  There are other forms of timezone specification, and indeed a date/time does not need a timezone at all.
4. You should not need to trim it off the `Z`.  Java's data-time parsers can parse the `Z` timezone specifier and give it its correct meaning ... if you use the right pattern.
5. If an ISO date time is "unparseable", that means that you have (explicitly or implicitly) used the wrong format to parse it.
6. Unfortunately, different countries (locales) have different default date / time formats, and worse still there is no reliable way (in general) to know which is the correct one to use ... if you don't know where it came from.
7. Fortunately ... ISO 8601 is an **international** standard.  If you see a date / time that conforms to the ISO 8601 syntax, you know what it means.
8. There are a number of kinds of ISO 8601 date and date/time representation as explained in the W3 Consortium [TR](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).  The different kinds can be distinguished without any ambiguity.
9. If you are parsing using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, then the correct pattern for this variation of ISO 8601 is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`.  The pattern that works with `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` is also `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`
10. The `DateTimeFormatter` class also defines a number of standard formats as constants.  The format for this kind of ISO 8601 date/time is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.  The other kinds are defined too.
11. The `Date` and `Calendar` classes and associated classes are *legacy* classes.  It is advisable to use the new `java.time` classes instead in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this convert method to `String to date` which is `ISO format`. But in generaly ISO format ends with `Z` , but if not no problem. This method returns Date, and do it what ever u want from this return value.

```
public static Date toCalendar( String isoDate)
            throws ParseException {
        String s = isoDate.replace("Z", "+00:00");
        try {
            s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);  // to get rid of the ":"
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new ParseException("Invalid length", 0);
        }
        return  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(s);

    }
```

In `Java8 TimeApi`  or later version has this usage,try it ;

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-09-09T09:04:47+01:00" );
Instant instant = offsetDateTime.toInstant();
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

Or use only this pattern  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Comment: Thanks, @drowny but it's not working. Also, I can't hardcode the values like "+00:00" because these are dynamic values which I will receive from APIs.

Comment: I added alternative way to solve, if u are using java8 or later version  try it please. Your string will be dynamic at the end "+00:00" or whatelse.